# Using holder for textview in listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I'm implementing a `ListView` with 2 `TextViews` in it. The first `TextView` is the name of the product that I'm populating from a query. When I touch any item in the `ListView` a `Dialog` appears. When I confirm the `Dialog` I would like to change the second `TextView` text to string but whenever I do so every second `Textview` text changes. For example, if I have 3 items in list view and I click the first one only that item's text view should change instead of all three.

This is my base adapter code:

```
public class StrengthAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Strengths> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private static HashMap<Integer, String> selectedStrengthsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private String testing;

    public StrengthAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Strengths> list, String test) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.testing = test;
        //HashMap<Integer, String> issuesStrengthsbrandNameIDMap = context
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //viewHolder.position = position;
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.strengthslistview, null);
            viewHolder.strengthCheckBox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strengthsCheckBox);
            viewHolder.chip = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chip);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.strengthCheckBox.setText(((Strengths) list.get(position)).getStrength_title());
        viewHolder.chip.setText(testing);
        //viewHolder.position = position;
        return convertView;
    }

    public static HashMap<Integer, String> sendSelectedStrengthMap(){
        return selectedStrengthsMap;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView strengthCheckBox;
        TextView chip;
        //int position;
    }
}
```

This is how my I set my adapter initially:

```
strengthListView.setAdapter(new StrengthAdapter(StrengthOfDemandsView.this, strengthsList, "TEST"));
```

and this is how I set my adapter after closing the dialog:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                strengthListView.setAdapter(new StrengthAdapter(StrengthOfDemandsView.this, strengthsList, "TEST123"));

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the name of the `textView` you want to change ?

Comment: viewHolder.chip = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chip). This is textview I want to change after closing the dialog @JohnJoe

Comment: I think the reason is because `getStrength_title()` is refer to "TEST" too

Comment: No, getStrength_title() is a method from my POJO class

Comment: You mean 3 row of the listView `textView` are changing ?

Comment: It was just as an example. I want to change the textview of the item clicked instead all the other are changing too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle clicks inside of your adapter and not setting adapter every time click happens. It have to look like this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //viewHolder.position = position;
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.strengthslistview, null);
            viewHolder.strengthCheckBox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strengthsCheckBox);
            viewHolder.chip = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chip);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.strengthCheckBox.setText(((Strengths) list.get(position)).getStrength_title());
        convertView.setOnClickListener(
             // show dialog here and then in positiveButton callback call
             //viewHolder.chip.setText(testing);
        );
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all inflate your layout before creation of holder.
Then you need to define onclick behavior by implementing onclicklistener. I updated your getView method please implement this as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.strengthslistview, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        //viewHolder.position = position;

        viewHolder.strengthCheckBox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strengthsCheckBox);
        viewHolder.chip = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chip);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.strengthCheckBox.setText(((Strengths) list.get(position)).getStrength_title());
    viewHolder.chip.setText(testing);
    //viewHolder.position = position;
convertView.setOnClickListener(
             //you can do your job here what u want to do by clicking specific row
        );
    return convertView;
}
```

Also write your functionalities in the block I mentioned above in comments.